# How am I blocking connections to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is a fairly specific issue, but I'm at a loss for reasons to what might be happening.

We have SQL Server 2008 running on what we'll call ServerA. We can RDP in ServerA, we can ping ServerA. If we RDP into ServerA, we can open up SQL Server Management Studio and connect to all of the database instances running on ServerA just fine.

However,

We can't connect to any of those instances from anywhere else on the network. I don't think its a network problem, because if I can RDP and ping ServerA, then the network is fine. And I don't think its a permission thing, because if I'm RDP'd in, I can connect to all the instances just fine. It's almost like I've got some secret safety setting turned on that's preventing connections from any IP other than localhost, or something like that.

Does such a safety setting exist? I wouldn't know how to get into this state even I wanted to, so I have no idea how to get out of it.

Comment: Is the firewall blocking port 1433?

Comment: Yes, turns out the firewall is blocking port 1433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server allows connection via four different protocols:

- Shared Memory
- Named Pipes
- TCP/IP
- VIA

Of these, only Shared Memory is enabled if you've installed SQL Server with default settings.

**See the protocols**:

- RDP to your database server
- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager (SSCM): *Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager*
- In SSCM, expand the SQL Server 2008 Network Configuration node
- Select the *Protocols for [instancename]* node (*instancename* is the name of your database instance; mine is called SQLEXPRESS).

Shared Memory only works locally on the database server.  This is likely the protocol being used when you RDP to the server and open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

TCP/IP is normally used when connecting from a remote machine to the database server.  **TCP/IP uses ports**, and the **default port** for SQL Server is **1433**.  If you have a firewall installed on your database server, you may need to open this port.

**Enabling the TCP/IP protocol**:

- Double-click the *TCP/IP* protocol in the right pane
- Change the *Enabled* option to Yes and click OK
- You will need to restart the SQL Server service

**Restarting the SQL Server service**:

- Select the *SQL Server 2008 Services* node
- Right-click the *SQL Server([instancename])* service and choose *Restart*

---

You should now be able to connect SSMS from remote machines to SQL Server running on your database server.

Comment: When trying to connect SSMS, you may need to specify the protocol to use.  On the *Connect to Server* dialog, click the *Options >>* button to see the *Connection Properties* tab.  On that tab, change the **Network Protocol** dropdown from *<default>* to **TCP/IP** to force the protocol.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Turns out, we had port 1433 blocked, so contrary to my original assumption, it WAS a network problem.

Comment: Heh, @rockinthesixstring answered your question in just six little words while I was typing all this up :)

Comment: hmm... can I post it as an answer and get the rep? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Is the firewall blocking port 1433?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the SQL Browser Service is running.

Comment: If it's not that it has to be configuration manager settings for TCP/IP or a firewall issue.  I would think at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL Server Configuration Manager on ServerA to make sure the TCP/IP network protocol is enabled (it is disabled by default).  It also needs to be enabled in the client network configuration but it is enabled there by default.

Comment: Seems to be enabled. Only "Via" is disabled.